# Converting from .NET Core 5 to .NET Framework 4.8

Tags: c#, .net-5, .net-4.8

I need to convert (downgrade) a code from .NET Core 5 to .NET framework 4.8 for compatibility reason. This toy function below shows my problem.

This function works fine in .NET Core 5; but, in .NET framework 4.8, I get this error:

> Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'System.Collection.Generic.List<double?> and double?

Code:

```
public static Dictionary<double, List<double?>> ToyFunction(Dictionary<double, List<double?>> dic1)
{
    Dictionary<double, List<double?>> dtot = 
             dic1.Keys
                 .OrderBy(key => key)
                 .Select(key => new
                 {
                     Key = key,
                     Value = new List<double?>
                        (dic1.ContainsKey(key) ? dic1[key] : new double?[2]).ToList()
                 }).ToDictionary(grp => grp.Key, grp => grp.Value);
```

My guess is that the error is in

```
Value = new List<double?>
   (dic1.ContainsKey(key) ? dic1[key] : new double?[2]).ToList()...
```

I tried to explicitly convert by adding

```
 (new List<double?>) new double?[2]...
```

but that did not work. I appreciate your suggestions.

---

Solved! Thanks for the helpful comments. The solution that worked:

```
(dic1.ContainsKey(key) ? dic1[key] : (new double?[2]).ToList() ).ToList()
```

Comment: "*Converting from .Net Core 5 to .Net Framwork 4.8*" - that's kind of like leaving the circus to join the orphanage

Comment: You are right. But the host application only works in .NetFramework 4.8.

Comment: Your guess is correct, but you cannot cast an array to a List, try `(new double?[2]).ToList()` instead.

Comment: If you really need compatibility with Framework, target Standard so you don't have to rewrite again when you eventually rejoin civilization.

Comment: You can cast a list to (IEnumerable<double?>) though which would work as well, however your function seems to be confusing and well... confusing. What on earth are trying to do here? at the moment its an inefficient way of achieving not much at all

Comment: @TheGeneral. Thanks for the comment. The function was a useless toy just to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede, Thank you for the comment. Could you please elaborate on " target Standard"? It seems super important but I do not know what it means in practice.

Comment: .NET Standard is the common API between the various flavors of .NET. If you write a library targeting .NET Standard 2.0, you can use it in Xamarin apps, Unity games, and recent versions of .NET Core and .NET Framework. Microsoft has a chart somewhere showing which versions are compatible with which. Google is your friend.

Comment: Targeting standard means that you put all your Core functions in a library, and change the library's "Target framework" (from its Properties page) to `.NET Standard 2.0`. This results in your library being able to be consumed by both Core and Framework applications. Also see the [.NET Standard support matrix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard) which explains the 2.0 instead of 2.1.

Comment: Thank you to both for explaining @KevinKrumwiede & NPras.